# Google Charts: ERROR TypeError: "c is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror

I am using google charts to show Covid data from an API and even though the data is loaded in ngOnInit(), I am getting the error: ERROR TypeError: "c is undefined".
Here is my code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "./data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<google-chart [data]="geoChart" *ngIf=mapReady></google-chart>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']  
})
export class AppComponent {
  states_data = [['State','COVID-Confirmed Cases']];
  response: any[]=[];
  mapReady=false;
  constructor(public serv: DataService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.serv.getData().subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
        this.response=res.statewise;
        this.response.splice(0,1);

        for(let state of this.response){
          let temp = [state.state,Number(state.confirmed)];
          if( state.state=="Odisha"){
            temp = ['IN-OR',Number(state.confirmed)];
          }
          this.states_data.push(temp);
        }
        this.mapReady=true
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err)
      }
    );
  }
  
  public geoChart: any = {
    chartType: 'GeoChart',
    dataTable: this.states_data,
    options: {
      region: 'IN', // INDIA
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#00F919', '#0FFFE4', '#1FA20F','#156930','#033E3B']},
      resolution: 'provinces',
      backgroundColor: '#00000',
      datalessRegionColor: '#00000',
      defaultColor: '#00000',
      'height': 600,
    }
  };
}
```

I found some similar questions on Stack overflow but they were related to Data-tables, and I am using google-charts. Does anyone have any idea what could be it? If you need more information, I would be happy to provide it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe, this `*ngIf=mapReady` should be `*ngIf="mapReady"`?

Comment: @R.Richards, tried but doesn't help

Comment: console log this.states_data above this.mapReady=true. What value it has?

Comment: @Ritesh it has got the array of data

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, I still haven't found the cause.
I believe it is something in the installation or version.
It's not in your code.

Comment: See in: https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts/issues/217

Answer (score 0):

Replace you component with the below code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "./data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<google-chart [data]="geoChart" *ngIf="geoChart"></google-chart>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  states_data = [['State','COVID-Confirmed Cases']];
  response: any[] = [];
  geoChart;
  constructor(public serv: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serv.getData().subscribe( (res) => {
      if (res && res.statewise) {
          this.response = res.statewise;
          this.response.splice(0, 1);
          for (let state of this.response) {
            let temp = [state.state, Number(state.confirmed)];
            if ( state.state == "Odisha") {
                temp = ['IN-OR', Number(state.confirmed)];
            }
            this.states_data.push(temp);
          }
          this.geoChart = {
              chartType: 'GeoChart',
              dataTable: this.states_data,
              options: {
                region: 'IN', // INDIA
                colorAxis: {colors: ['#00F919', '#0FFFE4',
                        '#1FA20F','#156930','#033E3B']},
                resolution: 'provinces',
                backgroundColor: '#00000',
                datalessRegionColor: '#00000',
                defaultColor: '#00000',
              'height': 600,
              }
            };
        }
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your template, put **[type]**="your_type"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<google-chart [type]="GeoChart" [data]="geoChart" *ngIf=mapReady></google-chart>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']  
})
```

In my case the '**type**' was either **invalid** or null.